# .net fw 3.5 Environment Properties

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, 64-bit

I wrote a code in .net 4.0 about OS version.32 bit or 64 bit control.

```
if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
            {
                try
                {
                    RegistryKey localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
                    localKey = localKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
                    if (localKey != null)
                    {
                        value64 = localKey.GetValue("ProductId").ToString();
                    }
                    return value64;
                }
```

Like this.I searced equal in .net 3.5 "Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem" and I can't this property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine which version of Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344166/how-to-determine-which-version-of-windows)

Comment: There is no "equal" in 3.5, there is no OpenBaseKey() method either.  By far the simplest solution is to just change the Platform target setting of your EXE project to "AnyCPU".

Comment: @HansPassant sorry it doesn't work.